# connect django to mysql on shared hosting

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.6

I want to use mysql server in my django project and this was my database setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
    }
}
```

but this engine needs **mysqlclient** and i can't install it on shared host. because i need superuser access to fix some issues.

So i decided to use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        ...
    }
}
```

however, this engine has some bugs!! when i wanna get a row from database, it doesn't return boolean columns(return **None** instead).

now i want to know if there is another engine for this or any other idea to solve it??

django==2.0
python==3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        ...
        'OPTIONS':{
                    'use_pure':True
                  }
               }
            }
```

it will use pure engine instead of c-extension.